# Using the command move-to with max-one-of and the error appears: MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead

Tags: netlogo

I'm new to NetLogo and I have a question that I'm sure is pretty basic. But, I'm not getting over the difficulty.

If anyone can help me overcome this difficulty, I would be very grateful.

I would like from the patch where the turtle is found to consider the 8 neighboring cells in search of the highest pveg value. If it has equally high values, choose 1 of these randomly. Upon finding the highest pveg value of the neighbors, the turtle went there.

I am using the command: max-one-of. I think it serves my purpose. But, I'm making some syntax error that shows the following error: MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead.

Thanks in advance

```
extensions [ gis ]
globals [ veg ]       
patches-own [pveg]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  setup-patches
  crt 1 [
   ask neighbors [ set pcolor blue ]
   set color black
  ]
 
end


to setup-patches
end

    
to go
  ask turtles [neighboring]
end

to neighboring
let my-neighWith-pveg [ neighbors with [pveg > 0.2] ]of patch-here   
ifelse neighWith-pveg = 0 
[  ] 

[ move-to max-one-of patches [my-neighWith-pveg] set pcolor red ;;ERROR HERE
    ]  
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NetLogo dictionary says, `max-one-of` needs an agentset and a reporter as input:

```
max-one-of agentset [reporter]
```

In your code, you use two agentsets: `turtles` and `my-neighWith-pveg`

Since you want to chose from the neighbors (and not all turtles) with the hightes pveg, you can write:

```
max-one-of my-neighWith-pveg [pveg]
```

Comment: Hi Lena, Thanks a lot for you answer. Helped a lot